# gradient registry has no entry for: FloorMod

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5

The mod operation claims to have no gradient defined. When running the code at the bottom of this post, I receive these messages:

```
LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: FloorMod
```

and

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'mod' (op type: FloorMod)
```

#### System information

- **OS Platform and Distribution**:
  Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from**:
  docker gpu image
- **TensorFlow version**:
  1.3.0
  v1.3.0-rc2-20-g0787eee 1.3.0
- **Python version**: 
  3.5.2
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:
  V8.0.61
- **GPU model and memory**:
  GeForce GTX 1080, 8GB

#### Source code / logs

A minimal reproducible example is found here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[5, 2])

# b = snt.Linear(output_size=4)(a)
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
b = tf.matmul(a, W) + b

loss = tf.reduce_sum(b) % 2
update_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(update_op, {a: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
```

This results in the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, 
grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, 
aggregation_method)
    511             try:
--> 512               grad_fn = ops.get_gradient_function(op)
    513             except LookupError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in 
get_gradient_function(op)
   1835     op_type = op.type
-> 1836   return _gradient_registry.lookup(op_type)
   1837 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-        packages/tensorflow/python/framework/registry.py in lookup(self, name)
     92       raise LookupError(
---> 93           "%s registry has no entry for: %s" % (self._name, name))

LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: FloorMod

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7b9ad04151d6> in <module>()
     10 
     11 loss = tf.reduce_sum(b) % 2
---> 12 update_op =     tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)
     13 
     14 sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-    packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss,     global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method,     colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    313         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
    314         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 315         grad_loss=grad_loss)
    316 
    317     vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-    packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in compute_gradients(self,     loss, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops,     grad_loss)
    384         gate_gradients=(gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_OP),
    385         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
--> 386         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
    387     if gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_GRAPH:
    388       grads = control_flow_ops.tuple(grads)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-    packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys,     name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method)
    514               raise LookupError(
    515                   "No gradient defined for operation '%s' (op type:     %s)" %
--> 516                   (op.name, op.type))
    517         if loop_state:
    518           loop_state.EnterGradWhileContext(op, before=False)

LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'mod' (op type: FloorMod)
```

Any idea on a work-around? I need to use modulo as part of my loss function.
I use it to convert some coordinates from global space to their relative position with a specific grid-cell (ask me if you want a better explanation - I don't suppose it's particularly relevant though).

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Gradients for FloorMod is added recently, but it is not included in TensorFlow 1.3.0. I have verified that your program works well if building TensorFlow from latest source code.

Some discussions can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6365).